# Isapi Rewrite not working, query string mod

Tags: url-rewriting, isapi-rewrite, helicontech

if you hypothetically typed in:
http://www.domain.com/Items-Shopping-Shoe-2013

my website needs to see:
http://www.domain.com/items.asp?Cc=Shoe-2013

so, I thought this would be pretty simple..

I edited the httpd.ini for helicon Isapi rewrite with this:

RewriteRule ^(.*?.com/)Items-Shopping-([A-Za-z0-9-]+)?$ $1items.asp\?Cc=$2

although patern matches, it doesn't work.

I am a newb to regex expressions and Isapi rewrite..probably pretty obvious :P

Comment: I did this in .htaccess file:

RewriteRule ^/Items-Shopping-([A-Za-z0-9-]+)?$ /items.asp?Cc=$1  [NC]

nothing :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following in ISAPI_Rewrite 3 .htaccess:

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^Items-Shopping-(.+)$ /items.asp?Cc=$1 [NC,L]
```

For ISAPI_Rewrite 2 it will be:

```
RewriteRule /Items-Shopping-(.+) /items.asp\?Cc=$1 [I,L]
```

Comment: for some reason, I didn't have an httpd.conf file in the install directory..  added one, and it began to work :)  I like your (.+) better than my ([A-Za-z0-9-]+).. thanks..  wish I could vote you up, but I'm a noob :P